# rails form nested hash in each do loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my method

```
  def categories
    @categories = {}
    cat = Category.includes(:sub_categories).where('categories.status = ?', true).order(:id)        
    cat.each do |category|
        category.sub_categories.each do |sub_category|
            @categories[category.name] = { name: sub_category.name }
        end
    end
  end
```

What I am trying to do is

Assume my **category.name** is mobile phones and my **sub_category.name** will have list of mobile phone brands. But my above method prints one sub category only because the name is variable but how to create nested hash.

Any other proper method of doing this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are overwriting the key in each subcategory. You have to store an array of subcategories for each key:

```
{"name1"=>[{"subcategory1"=>...},{"subcategory2"=>...}],"name2"=>[]}
```

Try this:

```
  def categories
    @categories = {}
    cat = Category.includes(:sub_categories).where('categories.status = ?', true).order(:id)        
    cat.each do |category|
        category.sub_categories.each do |sub_category|
            @categories[category.name] = [] unless @categories[category.name]
            @categories[category.name] << { name: sub_category.name }
        end
    end
  end
```

Also if the category.status is a boolean, you can do:

```
cat = Category.includes(:sub_categories).where(status: true).order(:id)
```

And remove the sql query from a controller, which is ugly.

EDITED

As long as you have a hash of arrays, in order to render the view you will have to iterate again:

```
@categories.each do |category, values|
  values.each do |sub_category|
    subcategory["what you need"]
  end
end
```

Comment: That is working I used like this in view `<% @categories.each do |category, sub_category| %>` I can show `<%= category %>` but how to view the sub_category I tried sub_category.name but throwing error

Comment: Because you have two hashes, not objects. Adding solution.